# Why did Jonas' gun jam?

Tags: dark

In *Dark* season 3, episode 7 Jonas tries to

> kill himself, first by hanging than by shooting himself.

In both cases it doesn't work:

> when trying to shoot himself,

the gun jams several times although it works perfectly well afterwards.

I understand the concept of determinism but I thought it to be a little bit over the top here. The general storylines of the two different worlds are more subtle.

My question is if something else is going on here or is it really just "clumsy and naïve" determinism (which in a way "doesn't feel right", if something like this can be said about a time-travel show anyway)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gun keeps jamming because older Jonas already lives.  You can't create this type of paradox, killing ones younger self within the time loop.  The main way the show illustrates this is certain events need to repeat in the timeline, they can not be altered.  The Bootstrap Paradox and Causal Loops are the main culprits here.  Two scenes that stand out, Tannhaus being given the completed time machine in 1986 and asked to complete it.  He said he wanted absolutely nothing to do with it, but ultimately repaired the older time machine, when asked why his response was along the lines of "I couldn't help myself".  Even the Stranger, when leaving the timemachine, said "I was told to do this."  Better example still is Mikkel.  Who wasn't even contemplating suicide until Jonas told him he killed himself the next day (sorry to the English teachers reading that.)

Sidebar below:

You could call it determinism, it's along the right lines.  Like you said, and I agree, it doesn't feel like determinism mainly because of the time travel element.  But I have trouble putting into words the reasons determinism doesn't fit.

I'd say the characters choices feel more like Rats in a maze.  Determinism to me, the Maze would only be 1 part of their lives, but that's not the case, it's their whole existence.  If they don't do XYZ, they won't get the cheese, and they have to get the cheese because they've always gotten the cheese.

Comment: I still have a question with the premise that the younger self cannot die till their older self lives. What about at the end when  [Sorry we cannot put spoiler tags in comments]                                                                 Jonas and Martha fixed the timeline and both their younger and older selves get erased?